# Indexed databases in Random Access Memory

Tags: c#, java, .net, sql, database

I'm currently writing a small test web application for a jobs search system.
I have a table **Vacancies** (the main table to talk about).
I need to make a rapid AJAX update of vacancies **(in a suggest list below input control)** matched to a user query. Different DBMS provide powerful programming extensions like **Free Text Search** in Microsoft SQL Server .. but I think that scanning a physical file takes plenty of time. And my idea is based on transfering the whole table **Vacancies** into RAM, so it, in my view, makes sense since in this case data retrieving demands less time. 
So if a client types in a textbox something like "pro" - the suggest list shows up with suggestions:

```
        -product manager 
        -professional designer 
        -programmer 
        -programmer C#
        -programmer Java
        -property administrator
        -provision expert
```

when a user types another letter "g", the value of a textbox widens to **"prog"**
and the list is refreshed:

```
        -programmer 
        -programmer C#
        -programmer Java
```

To make that possible I plan to create a tree index with saved values in nodes, where a **vacancy prefix** will play a role of the **index key** and node values are the **vacancy** names. The index is built and populated only **once** with data from a data table. See what I mean below:

```
 "pro" -> {
           "product manager", 
           "professional designer",
           "programmer",
           "programmer C#",
           "programmer Java"
           "property administrator",
           "provision expert" 
           }
```

So an index builder must analyze a string list and find **the least prefixes** of vacancy names. 
Then when a builder finds a string with a letter after prior found prefix, it creates a child tree node **("prog")** (the count of data values in that node decreases as it is constantly filtered) and adds itself up to the parent node **("pro")**

```
"prog" -> {
           "programmer", 
           "programmer C#",
           "programmer Java"} 
           }
```

Can you advise me on the types of tree indexes that naturally fit to solve this problem?
What's the best of them by the seek time? 
Thanks

Comment: Most relational databases store indexes in B-trees which means a search for `'prog%'` on an indexed column would be fairly quick.  Databases will also intelligently cache tables and indexes into memory.  You might be reinventing something the database already does behind the scenes.  Have you determined doing a dumb-ole query is too slow?

Comment: Most any database will likely not be too slow for anything you are submitting via ajax.

Comment: what if an application is distributed between 2 servers: DBMS mounted on a server 1, application logic is running on server 2, and **server 1** has not enough RAM to hold my table index. I know it's unlikely to happen, but just for an example to show it. I just need some practice to feel what is indexing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved years ago, you are recreating [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/):

For what it's worth the type of tree you want is a Patricia Tree or a Radix Tree.  In terms of storing all data in RAM, this is a bad idea because there are other applications that use RAM not just your index.  Currently I am ripping out someone's custom database that they thought was a good idea to implement this way and replacing it with a real database solution.

Comment: thanks, dude! You've helped me out .. now googling Radix Tree